# Unable to register service worker in angular using angular cli

Tags: angular, mean-stack, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I am trying to covert my angular app into a PWA so tried to add service worker using `npm install @angular/service-worker --save` and `ng add @angular/pwa` then after that I build the app in production mode using `ng build --prod` and serve the app using `ng serve --open` but there in console --> application tab I got `manifest.json` running fine but `service worker` is not getting registered and showing nothing in service worker section.

Here is my [src/index.html](https://pastebin.com/1deL9jwV)
Here is my [src/main.ts](https://pastebin.com/4BhufGr4)
Here is my [angular.json](https://pastebin.com/3CZSHFQH)
Here is my [ngsw-config.json](https://pastebin.com/7ZaExA7W)
Here is my [src/app/app.module.ts](https://pastebin.com/68ZXy8ui)

Comment: Hi .. is you app in https ??

Comment: No I am trying it on http://localhost:4200

Comment: read my answer ...

Answer (score 2):

Service Worker run `ONLY ON HTTPS` domain .. if you test it on localhost it can't work .. maybe try to run your localhost site with angular cli with:

```
ng serve --prod --ssl=true
```

Hope it helps you

try also in the main.ts file :

```
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .then(() => {
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator && environment.production) {
      navigator.serviceWorker.register('/ngsw-worker.js', {
        updateViaCache: 'none'
      }).then((sw) => {
        sw.update();
      });
    }
  })
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

and double check your dist folder for all necessary files :

`ngsw-worker.js`

and

```
 ngsw.json
```

as you see in screentshot

[image]

Comment: But when I have used only HTML, CSS as frontend and node.js backend then I  the service worker (which I have coded myself)  in localhost was working fine .                                           I have used the above command but it is not working and getting ```Your connection is not private
Attackers might be trying to steal your information from localhost (for example, passwords, messages or credit cards). Learn more
NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID```

Comment: yes cause it's not a HTTPS cert from an trusted authority (it's made by you) .. continue to advance and accept it ... in angular you have to be sure to have the flag production : true AND run it in HTTPS

Comment: HI , I have deployed the [app](https://deploy-pwa-49269.firebaseapp.com/) on firebase and tried but still not getting service worker registered .                                      Please check it and  tell me what has went wrong .

Comment: ok .. if you check the console .. it gives you an error ... DOUBLE CHECK IF THE SERVICE WORKER FILES ARE IN THE DIST FOLDER (I THINK NO) .. remember you have to put in your agular.json file .. under the assets array ... like:  "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets",
              "src/manifest.json" //< -- manifest.json
            ],

Comment: I have checked it's there in angular.json "assets":["src/manifest.json" , ...] and also in the dist/PWA/manifest.json . Do not know why not registering still .                            If you have made any in past then plz share the repo link with me I will try to look into that as well .

Comment: But still getting ```SecurityError: Failed to register a ServiceWorker: The script has an unsupported MIME type ('text/html')``` in the console .

Comment: Usually that error means there no scripts .. check if in dist folder there are also ngsw-worker.js and ngsw.json .. i ''l update answer with improve ts

Comment: yes , there is ```dist/PWA/ngsw-worker.js```, ```dist/PWA/ngsw.json``` , ```dist/PWA/safety-worker.js``` , ```dist/PWA/worker-basic.min.js``` , ```dist/PWA/index.html``` , ```dist/PWA/assets```, ```dist/PWA/runtime.ec2944dd8b20ec099bf3.js``` ,```dist/PWA/polyfills.9d3a8743be9f041e6ba8.js```, ```dist/PWA/manifest.json``` , ```dist/PWA/main.75afe3d2bc5505c5e3d7.js```, ```dist/PWA/styles.9c72e1371d65998f07ee.css``` .

Comment: do you publish it in a root folder .. or do you publish inside the PWA folder?

Comment: if you check the network tab .. it can't FIND the https://deploy-pwa-49269.firebaseapp.com/ngsw-worker.json file

Comment: My all files  found in ```dist/PWA``` on firebase  and here is my [hosting.cache](https://pastebin.com/VgfN8Fs3) . Please check my index.html file as I have given in question , is the base href creating any issue ??